# Kohana 3.2 does not load the config files

Tags: nginx, kohana, config, kohana-3

I am developing a web app using Kohana 3.2 with the following modules loaded:

- useradmin
- auth
- database
- orm
- pagination
- oauth
- kohana-email

On my development machine (Mac OS X Lion with Apache) everything its fine.

On my web server running ubuntu 10.04 with nginx 1.1.0 the config files are not loaded.

This comes to effect when i try to login. Kohana gives me the following error:

```
A valid hash key must be set in your auth config.
```

If I have a look at Kohana::$config, it is empty. Which gives me the conclusion that the my configurations are not loaded.

Does anyone have an idea what can cause such a behavior.

My directory looks like this

```
application/
├── bootstrap.php
├── cache
├── classes
│   ├── controller
│   │   ├── …
│   └── model
├── config
│   ├── auth.php
│   ├── database.php
│   └── pagination.php
├── i18n
│   └── …
├── logs
│   └── …
├── messages
└── views
    └── template
        └── default.php
```

EDIT: For I suppose the error must be in my server environment, here is my nginx configuration.

server {
        listen 80;

```
    root /srv/www/;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /index.php {
            fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV development;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax has been changed a little in 3.2

`Kohana::$config` will stay empty until you actually load the config file into it, with:

```
Kohana::$config->load('auth')
```

This has been addressed in the user guide in the [migration from 3.1.x section](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/upgrading).

Comment: That dies not lead to success. The $config variable remains empty. I suppose the error needs to be search in my server environment for the application is working when running on my development machine.

Comment: Hmmm...strange. Check if your config folder has a write permission. It is not important in this case, but it has to be writable